# How do you make two turtles draw at once in Python?

Tags: python, turtle-graphics, python-turtle

How do you make two turtles draw at once? I know how to make turtles draw and how to make two or more but I don't know how you can make them draw at the same time.
Please help!

Comment: you might be able to run each turtle in its own thread ... although generally speaking this is usually not a good idea ...

Comment: Same question but with code: [Python Multiple Turtles Moving (seemingly) Simultaneously](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44056498/python-multiple-turtles-moving-seemingly-simultaneously). I suggest using that as the future dupe target.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a minimalist example using timer events:

```
import turtle

t1 = turtle.Turtle(shape="turtle")
t2 = turtle.Turtle(shape="turtle")

t1.setheading(45)
t2.setheading(-135)

def move_t1():
    t1.forward(1)
    turtle.ontimer(move_t1, 10)

def move_t2():
    t2.forward(1)
    turtle.ontimer(move_t2, 10)

turtle.ontimer(move_t1, 10)
turtle.ontimer(move_t2, 10)

turtle.exitonclick()
```